# Ruby how to sort hash of hashes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have that deep Hash of hashes:

```
my_hash = { 
    :category_1 => {
        :solution_1 => { :order => 1 },
        :solution_2 => { :order => 2 }
    },
    :category_2 => {
        :solution_3 => { :order => 3 },
        :solution_4 => { :order => 4 }  
    }
}
```

I want to sort :solution_* hashes under :category_* hashes by key :order. Any suggestions?

(fixed)

Comment: What do you want as the result? Do you want one level of nesting removed? Otherwise your hash already is ordered...

Comment: What output do you want? the :category hashes or the :dummy hashes? And, what if one had orders `1` and `4` and the other had orders `2` and `3`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, you didn't specify your question, so I'm assuming you want one layer removed. I changed the starting hash a bit to actually see if the sorting works:

```
my_hash = { 
    :category_1 => {
        :solution_1 => { :order => 2 },
        :solution_2 => { :order => 3 }
    },
    :category_2 => {
        :solution_3 => { :order => 4 },
        :solution_4 => { :order => 1 }  
    }
}

Hash[my_hash.inject({}) { |h, (k, v)| h.merge(v) }.sort_by { |k,v| v[:order] }]
#=> {:solution_4=>{:order=>1}, :solution_1=>{:order=>2}, :solution_2=>{:order=>3}, :solution_3=>{:order=>4}}
```

*EDIT:*

Taking into account your clarification (and still starting from the modified unsorted hash I posted above):

```
sorted = my_hash.inject({}) do |h, (k, v)| 
  h[k] = Hash[v.sort_by { |k1, v1| v1[:order] }] 
  h 
end
#=> {:category_1=>{:solution_1=>{:order=>2}, :solution_2=>{:order=>3}}, :category_2=>{:solution_4=>{:order=>1}, :solution_3=>{:order=>4}}}
```

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you have the following hash of people to ages:

```
people = {
  :fred => { :name => "Fred", :age => 23 },
  :joan => { :name => "Joan", :age => 18 },
  :pete => { :name => "Pete", :age => 54 }
}
```

use sort_by to get where we want to go:

```
people.sort_by { |k, v| v[:age] }
  # => [[:joan, {:name=>"Joan", :age=>18}], 
        [:fred, {:name=>"Fred", :age=>23}],
        [:pete, {:name=>"Pete", :age=>54}]]
```

Comment: That changes `people` from a  hash of hashes to an array of arrays, though.